# TFS 2015 does not find UWP Unit Test

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, tfs-2015

I have the following problem:

If I try to do continous integration in TFS with my UWP project. The UWP Unit Test solution is not recognize as Unit Test, therefore the unit test will not be tested. Do I have to write an additional runsetting file?

I tried it with a normal Unit Test Solution then it worked.

Is there a solution for this, or is the TFS2015 not able to invoke UWP unit test?

Regards
Kaffi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some more configurations for the build agent to run build and test for UWP projects. Please refer to this link for details: [Build and test a Windows Store app using Team Foundation Build](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh691189%28v=vs.120%29.aspx)

Comment: Yes thanks, but the problem is now that I have multiple appx files in the solution. I always get the error that for testing only one appx file is allowed. Is there a possiblity to test multiple appx files during the unit test.

Comment: It seems that it's not possible to unit test Windows 10  UWP App  on a Windows Server 2012 R2.....

Comment: were you able to execute on Windows Server 2016? is this supported there? @Eddie-MSFT